# Hover Dropdown JS does not work with my Angular JS Setup

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-router

I am using a Bootstrap 3 based template called Unify and implemented Angular JS with ui-routing. Most of it works fine. Just my whole navigation is in the header and I use ng-include to inject the header from a html template file. Them the hover dropdown js plugin does not work anymore. My Code looks something like this.

```
<header ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></header>
<!--=== Content Part ===-->
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row" >
    <div ui-view autoscroll="false"></div>
</div>

<footer ng-include="'templates/footer.html'"></footer>
```

and the plugin is called before the  tag with the rest of scripts needed.

It works fine when I use the files as is without the Angular JS it also works fine with Angular JS if I don't inject the code but leave it in the index.html as is but not as now.

Hopefully somebody can help me out because I have the same problem with the parallax slider with for convenience sake I just keep in the index.html for now.

Thanks,

Gerd

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the detailed answer Chris T gave me in another question I found it is a scope related issue. Now I am loading the hover dropdown js within the template file and it works fine.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your answer?  <script> tags within a template cause the error mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331529/can-angularjs-ng-include-load-a-jinja2-processed-html-on-flask  So, how did you load the hover dropdown js?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and tried loading the hover dropdown js in a script tag in the template.  That resulted in an error (Like the one here: [Can AngularJS ng-include load a Jinja2 processed html on FLASK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331529/can-angularjs-ng-include-load-a-jinja2-processed-html-on-flask))

So instead of doing that, I got it to work by creating a controller for my template and inside the controller I added the drop down hover via:

$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdownHover(options);